# Using a loop in VagrantFile to create X number of disks

Tags: loops, vagrant, disk, vagrantfile

I am trying to create a vm with vagrant with multiple disks, but I want the vagrantfile to use a loop to create them. Vagrant does not handle loops correctly as it seems to double or triple traverse the loop. Then Vagrant fails as it already created disk1.vdi

Warning: I am no expert on Ruby...

I have tried using arrays and ruby's .each method. Tried a while loop. All fail with the same problem.

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
          Drives = [1,2,3,4,5]
          Drives.each do |hd|
                puts "harddrive #{hd}"
                v.customize ['createhd', '--filename', "./disk#{hd}.vdi",'--variant', 'Fixed', '--size', 20 * 1024]
                v.customize ['storageattach', :id,  '--storagectl', 'IDE', '--device', hd+1, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', "./disk#{hd}.vdi"]  
          end
  end

end
```

What I expect is a vm with 5+1 drives

what I get is

```
$ vagrant up
harddrive 1
harddrive 2
harddrive 3
harddrive 4
harddrive 5
/home/brian/projects/centos/Vagrantfile:7: warning: already initialized constant Drives
/home/brian/projects/centos/Vagrantfile:7: warning: previous definition of Drives was here
harddrive 1
harddrive 2
harddrive 3
harddrive 4
harddrive 5
/home/brian/projects/centos/Vagrantfile:7: warning: already initialized constant Drives
/home/brian/projects/centos/Vagrantfile:7: warning: previous definition of Drives was here
harddrive 1
harddrive 2
harddrive 3
harddrive 4
harddrive 5
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'centos/7' version '1905.1' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
A customization command failed:

["createhd", "--filename", "./disk1.vdi", "--variant", "Fixed", "--size", 20480]

The following error was experienced:

#<Vagrant::Errors::VBoxManageError: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["createhd", "--filename", "./disk1.vdi", "--variant", "Fixed", "--size", "20480"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create medium
VBoxManage: error: Could not create the medium storage unit '/home/brian/projects/centos/disk1.vdi'.
VBoxManage: error: VDI: cannot create image '/home/brian/projects/centos/disk1.vdi' (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreateMedium(HandlerArg*)" at line 462 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
>

Please fix this customization and try again.
```

Comment: Since this is a problem with creating additional hard drives and not with the code, you may have better luck on Super User.

Comment: Does this help?:
http://cobbaut.blogspot.com/2014/04/vagrant-creating-10-vms-with-6-disks.html

Comment: those examples create X number of machines with a constant number of drives.

Answer (score 1):

I think the important parts are the --portcount at storagectl and the unless File.exist? to avoid trying to recreate the disks

```
servers = [
  { :hostname => "node01", :ip => "192.168.1.10", :memory => "2048", :disks => 2 },
  { :hostname => "node02", :ip => "192.168.1.20", :memory => "2048", :disks => 2 },
  { :hostname => "node03", :ip => "192.168.1.30", :memory => "2048", :disks => 2 },
]


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "centos/7"
    servers.each do |conf|
        config.vm.define conf[:hostname] do |node|
            node.vm.hostname = conf[:hostname]
            node.vm.network "private_network", ip: conf[:ip]
            node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
                vb.customize ['storagectl', :id, '--name', 'SATA Controller', '--portcount', conf[:disks]+1]
                (1..conf[:disks]).each do |x|
                    file_to_disk = './disk_'+conf[:hostname]+'_'+x.to_s()+'.vdi'
                    unless File.exist?(file_to_disk)
                        vb.customize ['createhd', '--filename', file_to_disk, '--size', 20 * 1024]
                    end
                    vb.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'SATA Controller', '--port', x, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', file_to_disk]
                end
                vb.memory = conf[:memory]
            end
        end
    end
end
```